# Raspberry PI NOOBS first boot screen only three options. No OpenElec option

Tags: boot, noobs

When I copy and paste the NOOBS package onto a fresh microsd and load it into my pi, on first startup I get only three options:

1. Raspbian
2. Data Partition
3. Raspian - Boot to Scratch

From all the articles I read, I was supposed to get more than three like OpenElec etc. Can someone please help on how to get other options in NOOBS first boot screen.

Comment: Download it from http://openelec.tv/get-openelec write to sdcard 5.0.6 is now  optimized for rpi & rpi2

Answer (score 7):

I'm guessing it's because it isn't online -- Raspbian is the only one that's actually installed on the card, the others require network access to download, so if there isn't any such access, there isn't those options.

The easiest way to ensure network access is to plug in an ethernet cable.

Comment: Thanks a lot. When I gave the Ethernet connection I see all options.

Comment: Good -- please tick this as the correct answer if it solved your problem.